# Write and read test files in dictionary format

Tags: python, dictionary, text-files

This Question may have been asked before but I'm not getting any relevant results.

I am making a configuration file (text file). This file is like a dictionary, so that users can modify data easily. Now I want to fetch only the required key or in some case append new key and value in a systematic way.

My text file looks like this

```
MODULES={
    button:C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\hello.py,
    app1:C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\smarty.py,
}

USER={
    user1=password,
    user2=password,
    user1=password, 
}
```

I want to read this file using Python and return key when queried :

For example:

```
>> MODULES["button"]
C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\hello.py
```

Comment: "I am making a configuration file", why not use json?

Comment: or: why not use `yaml`? or any other existing format?

Comment: @hiro because [**`json`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) is supported out-of-the-box

Comment: @PeterWood: oh, i see. keep forgetting that yaml is not... my bad!

Comment: You could use the standard INI file format using the ConfigParser module

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most convenient way to solve the problem you are facing is to change the format of the configuration file. As mentioned in the comments section, `JSON` is supported out of the box in Python.

Hence, you can use something such as this `config.json`

```
{    
  "MODULES": {
           "button": "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\hello.py",
           "app1": "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\smarty.py",
          }

  "USER" = {
            "user1" = password,
            "user2" = password,
       }
}
```

You can use the `json` module to manipulate the file.

```
import json

with open('config.json', 'r') as config_file:    
    data = json.load(config_file)

print(data["MODULES"]["button"])
# make some changes to `data`

with open('config.json', 'w') as config_file:    
    json.dump(data, config_file)
```